# Lottery probability of Picking 9 Numbers on Ticket with 6 Numbers for Jackpot

Tags: probability, statistics

I understand the lottery probability for normal based lottery of having a ticket of $K$ ball selections on a single ticket, $N$ balls in the lottery, and $B$ matching balls for a win, and the number of balls that are drawn is also $B$, with usual values of $$K = 6$$$$N=1 .. 49$$$$B=6$$

This should then give the probability as $$\frac{{K\choose B}{N-K\choose K-B}}{{N\choose K}}=\frac{{6\choose 6}{49-6\choose 6-6}}{{49\choose 6}}=\frac{{6\choose 6}{43\choose 0}}{{49\choose 6}}=13,983,816$$. All standard stuff taken from

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lottery_mathematics#Odds_of_getting_other_possibilities_in_choosing_6_from_49

But what if I'm playing a lottery whereby I can buy a ticket that has 9 numbers on the ticket which I think makes $K=9$, there are still $N=49$ balls in the lottery, I still only need $B=6$ balls for a jackpot, and the number of balls drawn is still $B$. Is the formula to calculate probability still:
This should then give the probability as $$\frac{{K\choose B}{N-K\choose K-B}}{{N\choose K}}=\frac{{9\choose 6}{49-9\choose 9-6}}{{49\choose 9}}=\frac{{9\choose 6}{40\choose 3}}{{49\choose 9}}=2,475$$

Please can someone tell me if this is correct or not? Or does the formula change since the ticket contains more numbers etc